# How to initialize variable through fetching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I tried to develop game, through fetching,I can get some data.

I locate 'retry' button,and by clicking them,I can transit to default page.

When I try 2nd game,some error occured.

It may come from some variable `clicked`and`correct` didn't initialize to '0'.

are there any problem declare position ?

If someone has some opinion,please let me know. sorry for long work below.

```js
// const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var apikey = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=2&type=multiple";

$(".btn").on("click", ".start", function() {
  let clicked = 0;
  let correct = 0;

  $(".header").text("Is fetching...");
  $(".content").text("just a moment please");
  $(".start").hide()

  fetch(apikey)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      display(json, 0);
      $(".btn").on("click", ".choice", function() {
        console.log("clicked", clicked);
        correct += $(this).html() === json.results[clicked].correct_answer ? 1 : 0
        clicked++;
        console.log(correct);
        if (clicked == json.results.length) {
          showresult(correct);
        } else {
          display(json, clicked);
        }
      });

      $(".btn").on("click", ".retry", function() {
        console.log("#");
        document.querySelector('.btn').innerHTML = "<button class='start'>start</button>";
      });
    });
});

function display(json, clicked) {
  const arr = [json.results[clicked].correct_answer].concat(json.results[clicked].incorrect_answers);

  $(".header").text("Question" + Number(clicked + 1));
  $(".category").text("[category] : " + json.results[clicked].category);
  $(".difficulty").text("[difficulty] : " + json.results[clicked].difficulty);
  $(".content").text(json.results[clicked].question);
  let html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    html += "<button class='choice'>" + shuffle(arr)[i] + "</button><br>";
  }
  document.querySelector('.btn').innerHTML = html;
}

function showresult(correct) {
  $(".header").text("Number of correct answers is " + correct);
  $(".category").hide()
  $(".difficulty").hide()
  $(".content").text("Challenge again");

  document.querySelector('.btn').innerHTML = "<button class='retry'>retry</button>";
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="header">Welcome</h1>

  <h2 class="category"></h2>
  <h2 class="difficulty"></h2>
  <hr>
  <h3 class="content">Press the following button</h3>
  <hr>

  <div class="btn">
    <button type="button" class="start">Start</button>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you start a game you add another `click` handler to the `.choice` buttons. So when you play the second game, the handler runs twice when you click on the button.

You should just bind the handler once, not every time you click.

You'll need to move some of the variables out to global variables.

```js
// const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var apikey = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=2&type=multiple";
let clicked;
let correct;
let global_json;

$(".btn").on("click", ".start", function() {
  clicked = 0;
  correct = 0;

  $(".header").text("Is fetching...");
  $(".content").text("just a moment please");
  $(".start").hide()

  fetch(apikey)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      global_json = json;
      display(json, 0);
    });
});

$(".btn").on("click", ".choice", function() {
  console.log("clicked", clicked);
  correct += $(this).html() === global_json.results[clicked].correct_answer ? 1 : 0
  clicked++;
  console.log(correct);
  if (clicked == json.results.length) {
    showresult(correct);
  } else {
    display(global_json, clicked);
  }
});

$(".btn").on("click", ".retry", function() {
  console.log("#");
  document.querySelector('.btn').innerHTML = "<button class='start'>start</button>";
});

function display(json, clicked) {
  const arr = [json.results[clicked].correct_answer].concat(json.results[clicked].incorrect_answers);

  $(".header").text("Question" + Number(clicked + 1));
  $(".category").text("[category] : " + json.results[clicked].category);
  $(".difficulty").text("[difficulty] : " + json.results[clicked].difficulty);
  $(".content").text(json.results[clicked].question);
  let html = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    html += "<button class='choice'>" + shuffle(arr)[i] + "</button><br>";
  }
  document.querySelector('.btn').innerHTML = html;
}

function showresult(correct) {
  $(".header").text("Number of correct answers is " + correct);
  $(".category").hide()
  $(".difficulty").hide()
  $(".content").text("Challenge again");

  document.querySelector('.btn').innerHTML = "<button class='retry'>retry</button>";
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="header">Welcome</h1>

  <h2 class="category"></h2>
  <h2 class="difficulty"></h2>
  <hr>
  <h3 class="content">Press the following button</h3>
  <hr>

  <div class="btn">
    <button type="button" class="start">Start</button>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I would like to understand why click handler bind twice every time the game started. What is the direct cause of this issue?  Thanks

Comment: Every time you call `.on()` you're adding a click handler. They don't replace each other.

Comment: And you were calling `.on()` every time you clicked on the `.start` button.